# javascript regexp help selecting a word but no the first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript, and I am trying to work out how to select all characters of a word but no the first character.

For this, I am using regExpr. So the following expresion:

`/\B[a-zA-Z'-]+/gi`

should select all characters except the first one of each word, but it doesn't work for the text:
"I'm a little tea pot"
because of the apostrophe. I have tried everything, but dont know what else.
I would apreciate any suggestion or support in this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to collect the matches into an array or replace those parts excep the first char?

Comment: Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v70vtc2p/). I suggest using `/\b([a-z])((?:['-]?[a-z]+)+)/gi` with an anonymous method inside a replace.

Comment: show how should look the final result

Comment: If you go to regxr.com, and you write a sentence, the final result would be to select all characters but not the first one. In my case it works, but I have the problem when I use the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
s = "I'm a little tea pot, let's pour me out";
re = /(\B|')[a-z-']+/gi;
lastLettersArray = s.match(re);
console.log(lastLettersArray);
```

output

```
["'m", "ittle", "ea", "ot", "et's", "our", "e", "ut"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try it here](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) (Choose JS, PHP is default tab): http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

As simple as:

```
string.match(/\B\w+/gi);
```

Comment: sorry, but that doesn't work, in fact I think it is what I have written. I have tried that expresssion earlier and it wasn't sucessfull.

Answer (score 1):

A matching regular expression pattern is as follows:

https://regex101.com/r/rW9sX5/2

```
/\b\S(\S+)/gi
```

[See the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/rW9sX5/2).

Comment: that was close, but it needs to select all characters of each word but not the first one of each

Comment: @galeonweb: Doesn't it work? Did you click the demo? I think it does that. Notice the match list in the pane on the right. Also, I updated it to make it simpler.

Comment: The ui on that site is a bit confusing but @Mowzer's answer is the right one

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach using `String.split` and `Array.slice` functions:

```
var str = "I'm a little tea pot", words = [];

str.split(" ").forEach((w) => w.length > 1 && words.push(w.slice(1)));

console.log(words);  // ["'m", "ittle", "ea", "ot"]
```

Or by using `RegExp.exec` function with regexp `/\b\w([\w'-]+)\b/g`:

```
var str = "I'm a little tea pot", words = "", res, re = /\b\w([\w'-]+)\b/g;

while ((res = re.exec(str)) != null){
    words += " " + res[1];
}

console.log(words);  // "'m ittle ea ot"
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

You can use `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/^.{1}|\s[a-z'-](?!=\s){1}|\s/` to exclude first character in word, match remainder of word; `for` loop, `String.prototype.replace()` to replace matched words returned by `.split()` following calling `.toLowerCase()` on matched word.

```js
var str = "I'M a liTtLe tEa pOt";
console.log("original string:", str);
var res = str.split(/^.{1}|\s[a-z'-](?!\s)|\s/)
          .filter(Boolean); // `["'m", "ittle", "ea", "ot"]`
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  str = str.replace(res[i], res[i].toLowerCase())
};
console.log("res array:", res, "replaced string:", str);
```

---

You can use `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `1` to return string excluding first character in `str`

```js
console.log("I'm a little tea pot".slice(1))
```

or `String.prototype.split()` and `Array.prototype.slice()` to return array excluding first character in `str`

```js
console.log("I'm a little tea pot".split("").slice(1))
```

Comment: @galeonweb Is expected result an array of each character following first character in string? Or entire string following first character in string? _"but I need a regEx"_ Why is `RegExp` necessary?

Comment: I need a regExp, because I dont want the solution of my essay, on the other hand I am stuck in this. The exercise is related with putting in lowercase all characters of an string of each word except the first of each word. for example: My Mum Loves Marhiuana ;)

Comment: @galeonweb _"The exercise is related with putting in lowercase all characters of an string of each word except the first of each word"_ Is this actual expected result? Have you considered including this description at Question?  Not certain interpret  _"I need a regExp, because I dont want the solution of my essay"_ correctly, here. What do you mean by "the solution of my essay"?

Comment: OK, It doesn't matter what my exercise is really, the question is quite simple I think, but I will explain better. If you know what regExp means, I only want how to select characters excluding the first character of each word. If I wanted to know how to sort an array or something else I don't think I have to explain you the whole context of the program, do I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116276/discussion-between-galeonweb-and-guest271314).